# "θ-subgraph" disambiguation.

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

This quote from the paper I'm currently reading:

> by θ-subgraph we mean a subgraph homeomorphic to $K_{\{3,2\}}$

I'm familiar with $\theta_{i,j}$ denoting either a subgraph consisting of $i$ paths through at least $j$ edges with the same pair of endpoints; or the similar notion but with an additional requirement for the paths to be internally disjoint (usually explicitly stated.)

Thus, I have two questions:

> 1. Where does the $\theta$ notation come from?

And,

> 2. What does $K_{\{3,2\}}$ mean in the context of the quote?

---

*It's possible that I'm missing something very obvious here; if that's the case, I'm sorry for the silly question.*

Comment: I was indeed completely missing that $K_{\{i,j\}} \equiv K_{i,j}$ (in a moment of confusion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph $K_{\{3,2\}}$ can be drawn to look like the Greek letter theta.

I presume that $K_{\{m,n\}}$ denotes the complete bipartite graph
with $m$ vertices on one side and $n$ vertices on the other.